# How to have indented text in ntheorem environment without a newline at the beginning?

Tags: spacing, indentation, theorems, paragraphs, ntheorem

I would like to have an indented paragraph inside a ntheorem environment where the first line is not indented. Using the quote-environment inside ntheorem lets the paragraph start with an ugly indentation after the theorem name, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{proposition}
\begin{quote}
\blindtext
\end{quote}
\end{proposition}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Which gives leads to:

[image]

Is there a way to remove the space between "Proposition 1" and the beginning of the paragraph? \noindent just lets the paraphraph start in a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quote` is a built on a list environment, and what you see is the space of `\leftmargin` followed by `\itemsep`.  To counteract this, back up by these amounts.:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{proposition}
  \begin{quote} \hspace*{\dimexpr-\leftmargin-\itemsep}
    \blindtext
  \end{quote}
\end{proposition}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

A similar approach should work for other list environments.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `quote` environment inside the `proposition` solely to get the text indented, you could set `\theoremindent` instead. Since you don't seem to want the header indented, you could misuse `\theoremheaderfont` to include a backspace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% choose your indentation here:
\theoremindent20pt 
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\hspace{-\theoremindent}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{proposition}
\blindtext
\end{proposition}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```